# how to remove comma from innerHtml, value coming from JSON in angular 4 ? image attached

Tags: angular

JSON Response:

```
{
            "qno": 1,
            "question": "What is HTML5? And, what are the new features?",
            "answer": [
                "<p>HTML is a markup language designed for processing, defining, presenting and formatting the text. The HTML5 is the latest version and has features like:</p>",
            "<ul class=\"none\"><li>Local Storage</li>",
            "<li>New form elements like date, time, url, range, color</li>",
            "<li>Canvas for 2D drawing</li>",
            "<li>Media elements like audio and video</li>",
            "<li>New semantic elements like, <code>nav</code>, <code>header</code>, <code>footer</code>, <code>section</code> and <code>article</code></li>",
            "<li>Local storage and Session storage instead of cookies.</li></ul>"
            ]
}
```

Bind the answer using innerHTML angular 4

[image: See image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the attempted code.

Comment: <li *ngFor="let htmlDatas of htmlData.questions; let i = index;">
        <p class="question-class" [innerHTML]="htmlDatas.question"></p> 
        <p class="answer-class highlight"  [innerHTML]="htmlDatas.answer" class="html"></p>
      </li>

Comment: ngFor htmlDatas.answer too

Comment: when binding the value, at the end of line comma also printed in it..
eg:  "<ul class=\"none\"><li>Local Storage</li>",
            "<li>New form elements like date, time, url, range, color</li>",
            "<li>Canvas for 2D drawing</li>",
            "<li>Media elements like audio and video</li>",

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
 htmlData.questions.forEach(data = > data.answer.replace(/<\/li>\",/g, '</li>');
```

replace string after you retrieve data in you object.

Comment: by using join() working fine... thanks
 <p class="answer-class "  [innerHTML]="htmlDatas.answer.join('')"></p>

Comment: @Mohan - please do accept upvote if answer helped you